# What has been your experience of building a browser website using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile-website

We've built an app through Flutter and realising that some of our user behaviour is best created for larger screens, where people are creating best on desktop. I've seen that the codebase is viable for transporting to a web experience. We want to avoid the desktop app and build for a browser.

Has anyone had experience with building for web browsers using Flutter?
What's been your experience? How good is the codebase for creating things such as:

- Messengers
- Posting and threads
- Spaces, like Pinterest folders or Padlet like these - [NewHope Crowdsource Space](https://mywondr.co/project/220fe4d5-19e1-419f-b00b-019799abca4b)

This is the [app on the store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mywondr.wondr&hl=en_GB&gl=US) if that helps.

I'd greatly appreciate any feedback, thoughts or experiences you've had. I'm wondering whether to invest in Flutter for web browser or whether I need to go back to JS.
Thank you

We're exploring whether to develop the website through a different language and looking for people's experiences if they've attempted this.

Comment: based on personal opinion.

Answer (score -2):

The experience is not much different than mobile development, if you're used to it, really I recommend you usage this variant. Only one source code for all platforms.

In addition, the use of libraries is practically the same. The only thing that changes is that it compiles to HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

I only recommend taking care of the adaptability to different screen sizes, using mediaQuery (height, width) and Expanded Widgets.
The rest stays the same, your HTTP requests (Dio is an excellent option). To work the logic layer also the BLoC design pattern helps a lot.